# Android/Java understanding when I'm able to use/overwrite variable

Tags: java, android

I have a variable that I get from shared preferences when I load the app.

I first initialize the variable

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final String camera_type = booth_preferences.getString("camera_key", "back");
```

Then later down the line, I get that variable and do something with it

```
if(camera_type.equals("front")){
        //do something
} else if(camera_type.equals("ext")){
        //do something
} else {
        //do something
}
```

Now, directly after that if statement, I have an onclick listener that is supposed to change and update that preference.

```
camera_button_front.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
        edit_preferences.putString(camera_key, "front").commit();
    }
});
camera_button_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
        edit_preferences.putString(camera_key, "back").commit();
    }
});
camera_button_ext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
        edit_preferences.putString(camera_key, "ext").commit();
    }
});
```

But when I try to change the variable `camera_type` I get errors stating "cannot assign a value to final variable 'camera_type'".

```
camera_button_ext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
        edit_preferences.putString(camera_key, "ext").commit();
        camera_type = "ext";
    }
});
```

I've ever reinstated the variable after the onclick hoping it would over write the variable completely.

```
camera_button_ext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    String camera_type;
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
        edit_preferences.putString(camera_key, "ext").commit();
        camera_type = "ext";
    }
});
```

If I were to remove the `final` then I'm not able to use the variable in the if statement.

I'm new to Java, so this should be a simple answer, I'm just not sure which combination of wrong I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your variable a non-final field. Then you can use it within the onClick (and all other methods of the class) and also reassign it as you wish.

```
private String camera_type; // member variable

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    camera_type = booth_preferences.getString("camera_key", "back");
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reassign value to a final variable. To make it accessible inside your onClick method, you could make camera_type a member variable of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one element massive

```
String[] cameraType = new String[0];
```

and use

```
if("some_String".equals(cameraType[0])){
//do smth
}
```